# Different behaviour of two identical RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewPager` with 2 fragments each with a `RecyclerView`. But there is one weird thing: animations of `notifyItemInserted()` and `notifyItemRemoved()` work well with the first one, but only `notifyItemRemoved()`animation works with the second one (notifying insertion acts like `notifyDataSetChanged()`).

**Initialization is identical:**

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**This is how I add items:**

```
data.add(position, item);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
```

Can you tell me why animation of `notifyItemInserted()` is not working?

Comment: Batter share a git repo of your working code or share more details.

Comment: use `notifyDataSetChange()`

Comment: I need animations that's why I need notifyItemInserted()